# Enclosing order of words

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

This is a very common phrase used in literary analysis but I can not find a neat Latin equivalent. The device is very common in Catullus c.64.(The same applies to a similar but not identical common term among literary critics, viz. ‘ring composition’, for which I now suggest narratio reversa.’) One brilliant ‘impressioistic’suggestion of a learned friend is amplexus verborum in usu poetico. Some examples are indeed hyperbaton,as in Catullus 64, like dicuntur liquidas Neptuni nasse per undas/ cum lecti iuvenes Argivae robora pubis/ auratam optantes Colchis avertere pellem (for which the pure Latin according to Quintilian is transgressio). I am thinking more of examples in Horace like the Pyrrha Ode book I, 5, l.1:- Quis multa gracilis te puer in rosa where the gracilis puer is placed between the multa and rosa and the te is neatly enclosed between the gracilis and puer. So multa and rosa enclose the gracilis puer, who embraces Pyrrha (‘te’) in the word order as well as in fact. That is enclosing word order. Hence, ‘amplexus verborum in usu poetico’.

Comment: Can you give examples of what you mean? I'm not sure if I follow you, and if this is hyperbaton or something else.

Comment: I don't have access now, and the question should be understandable without following any links and without reading comments. Can you add [edit] to add examples to the question and describe how what you are looking for relates to hyperbaton? Your comment clarifies the situation, but it'd be better to have that written and formatted in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and I should have explained fully what I meant but in the world of pedagogy I wrongly assumed it was a literary term familiar to all.  Apologies.

Comment: Thanks! Very few terms are known to all, so it's almost always a good idea to give a few examples or a link to a Wikipedia page. Comparison to and disambiguation from related terms is another good habit that helps get everyone on the same page. We all misjudge these things occasionally, so don't worry too much about a confusing first version.

Comment: What is the question? I don't understand what is being asked.

Comment: The question I am asking  is for a neat translation into Latin of the common use of this term used in literary criticism: ‘the enclosing order of words’. It is a kind of very ‘tight’ and nuanced  hyperbaton. Look at the example I have given above from Horace and note how in line 1  puer and gracilis entwine te; multa and rosa entwine them both. This is the glory of Latin word order. This ‘entwining’ here in not only in the word order but in actual fact. The courtesan, Pyrrha, lies between the boy astride her, while the many rose petals enclose both. This is known as ‘enclosing word order.